# NodeJs Express Server | How do I get /about

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

My code:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.get("/", (request, response) => {
    response.send("Hi there");
});

app.get("/about", (request, response) => {
    response.send("<h1>About</h1>");
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Listen on the port 3000...");
});
```

What would the url for "/about" be? "/" is "https://server.mdcpiganlwogakktg.repl.co"

I tried `https://server.mdcpiganlwogakktg.repl.co/about` and it didnt work

Comment: Your code shows an http server running on port 3000.  That would be `http://server.mdcpiganlwogakktg.repl.co:3000/about` unless there's some hosting infrastructure that is handling the https for you.   Or as a simpler test, try this from the actual host that the server is running on:  `http://localhost:3000/about` to see if your server is just up and running there.

Comment: Also make sure you restarted the server if you are not using nodemon.

Answer (score 0):

Just start the Server first by opening the code folder in terminal and type

node folderName.js

In Terminal will be printed

Listen on the Port 3000...